# HTML5 global metatags/style for mobile app

Tags: css, html, styles, meta

I am a C++ developer who recently started using HTML5 in my mobile apps, I don't have too much knowledge in the world of web programming and I would very much like some advice in order to fine tune my meta tags.

I need the perfect meta tags that would suit a mobile application for ios/android/windows phone/blackberry etc.

The problem is I am not sure what exactly I need and what I don't need, this is the list I have so far:

```
html, body
{
     overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: translate3d(0,0,0);

    transition: translate3d(0,0,0);

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px

    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */

    /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    background-color:#202020;
}

* {margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>$Title</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Test">
        <meta name="description" content="Test">
        <meta name="subject" content="Test">
        <meta name="copyright" content="Test">
        <meta name="url" content="http://www.test.com">
        <meta name="language" content="en-GB">
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <meta name="pagename" content="$Title">
        <meta name="coverage" content="Worldwide">
        <meta name="distribution" content="Global">
        <meta name="target" content="all">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="640">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="$Title">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="ResourceLoaderDynamicStyles" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8;" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

        <!-- Set a shorter title for iOS6 devices when saved to home screen -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Ratchet">

        <script>
        document.ontouchmove = function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        </script>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="Test">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

- user-scalable=no" this will block zooming in your app and I would suggest to not use (bad UX)

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="$Title">
```

- Launcher Title if you dont want to use title tag for this.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

- this will hide browser interface

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

- and this will change color of status bar in ios

---

You should add:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

-iOs launcher icons

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icon.png">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#222222">
```

- Windows icons

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup-image.png">
```

-iOs startup-image

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

- Android/Chrome homescreen

---

You dont need:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Test">
```

- no need for this, google and other search engines does not use keywords meta

```
<meta name="subject" content="Test">
```

- the subject of page. Not recommended

```
<meta name="copyright" content="Test">
```

- more for you then for anybody else

```
 <meta name="url" content="http://www.test.com">
```

-this is your full domain name or web address. for SEO

```
<meta name="language" content="en-GB">
```

- W3C is recommending to use `<html lang="en">` not the meta tag

```
<meta name="pagename" content="$Title">
```

- It is additional page title. No such tag in html5 spec?

```
<meta name="coverage" content="Worldwide">
<meta name="distribution" content="Global">
```

-defines the level or degree of distribution for crawlers but there are not recognized metadata then you shouldn't use them. invalid for HTML5

```
 <meta name="target" content="all">
```

- ??? not sure what it is:P some crazy windows thing old old one? No such tag in html5 spec?

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
```

- future for old windows phones to say that page is viewable on small screen

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="640">
```

- statement on what size of screen page was optimized for Windows but it is for old phone and it not really working. I would suggest use media queries for that.

```
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

- phone number detection for Safari on iOS (bad Ux if you disable this)

```
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
```

- Mobile IE smoothing fonts feature but this is not standard W3C tag. I would suggest do font smoothing in CSS.

```
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
```

- this was used in early demos. you need only `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

```
<meta name="ResourceLoaderDynamicStyles" content="">
```

- this should make browser to mark DOM before CSS is added. I dont think you should do that.

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

- cache things. Now days that kind of stuff is done server side.

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
```

- IE6 feature. Obviously no need

```
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off">
```

- DNS prefetching.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
```

- IE8/9 Compatible mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

- duplicated entry `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

```
   <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Set a shorter title for iOS6 devices when saved to home screen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Ratchet">
```

- duplicated entries